# SSL debugging in ONOS

Tags: java, ssl, sdn, onos

I'm trying to enable the SSL debugging in ONOS. My aim is to get symmetric key of the session. I found out that I have to use `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`, but I'm not sure where to use it and also where to check the log.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the ssl debug you have to add to the Java Virtual Machine the proper option `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`.

For example:

java -cp $MY_CLASS_PATH -Djavax.net.debug=ssl <..other options..> my.package.MyMainClass

If you have a bash script that launch your program, you should usually have an environment variable `JAVA_OPTS` or something like that, where you could add all your options and properties.

Or you have to change the script to put the debugging conf.

Comment: Should I see the debug messages on the onos-karaf terminal?

Comment: Thanks, I can see the messages on the onos-araf terminal.

Comment: It should follow the system loggin configuration, usually you should have this output on the console.